# Javascript dates are a day off?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to use a simple date function in my application to pass a date in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` such as `2017-07-30` and have it returned in the format of `07/30/2017`.

However, when I try this, I supply my date correctly but it outputs one day shorter than what I am looking for.

```js
function format(inputDate) {
    var date = new Date(inputDate);
    if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) {
        var day = date.getDate().toString();
        var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
        // Months use 0 index.

        return (month[1] ? month : '0' + month[0]) + '/' +
           (day[1] ? day : '0' + day[0]) + '/' + 
           date.getFullYear();
    }
}

console.log(format('2017-07-30'));
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49pptrj4/

Any thoughts as to why this is returning incorrectly?

Result on my end:

[image]

Comment: result seems correct in the snippet

Comment: your jsfiddle / code snippet is working correctly

Comment: It print out '2017-07-30' when I try :-?

Comment: could it be a timezone issue?

Comment: Updated with screenshot.

Comment: cant you just add +1 to make the date correct?

Comment: Try debugging. What does `console.log(new Date('2017-07-30'))` produce in your browser?

Comment: @cup_of - I'm sure I could but now I am curious why its working for others.

Comment: new Date('2017-07-31') returns `2017-07-31T00:00:00Z` - if you are west of GMT, that translates to some time on the 30th July - try using getUTCDate getUTCMonth and getUTCYear instead

Comment: @Phil `Sat Jul 29 2017 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

Comment: Ah, of course. @JaromandaX has pointed out the issue here. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) ~ *"Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are **treated as UTC**, not local."*

Comment: Ah sweet, thanks for the collaboration all, that seemed to fix it.

Comment: or add `T00:00:00` to inputDate `var date = new Date(inputDate+'T00:00:00');` - in Firefox, this is treated as LOCAL time

Answer (score 9):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone)

> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", [Date.]parse() assumes a local time zone, but given an ISO format such as "2014-03-07" it will assume a time zone of UTC.

Your date string is assumed to be 0:00, or midnight, on the date specified *in UTC*, the time zone of Greenwich, England. Your browser however takes this time and converts it to your local timezone, which is a few hours behind UTC if you're in the Americas, making the result a day behind.

The following code should work for creating a Date in the local timezone with the correct date.

```
utcDate = new Date("2017-07-30"); //Date object a day behind
new Date(utcDate.getTime() + utcDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) //local Date
```

Here the local Date is created by adding time based on the time zone difference. `getTimezoneOffset()` returns in minutes, so `* 60000` is needed to convert to milliseconds.

This might not work in areas ahead of UTC; it might advance an extra day.
Edit: Just checked and `getTimezoneOffset()` is negative in areas ahead of UTC so it will subtract time correctly.