# Javascript: Days off by one (Timezones)

Tags: javascript, date

I seem to be having a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407072/javascript-dates-are-a-day-off) thread, where my JS dates are 1 day off, but I'm struggling a little to use the answers for a solution.

My problem seems to be down to timezone differences, BST(+1) vs GMT

For example, the clocks go forward two days after the first (correct) example, and then the rest are off:

```
console.log(new Date('2022', '02', '24')); // 24 (2022-03-24T00:00:00.000Z)
console.log(new Date('2022', '09', '24')); // 23 (2022-10-23T23:00:00.000Z)
console.log(new Date('2022', '08', '24')); // 23 (2022-09-23T23:00:00.000Z)
```

From the docs and that thread: If I create a date using strings it'll be in UTC, which is an hour behind me currently. And so because I'm not providing a time it assumes 00:00, which is actually 23:00UTC the previous day, right?

So I should use `getTimezoneOffset()` if I want to get a consistent date 7 days ago?:

```
const oneWeekAgo = new Date(
    utcDate.getFullYear(), 
    utcDate.getMonth(), 
    utcDate.getDate() - 7
) + utcDate.getTimezoneOffset();
```

This seems to get the date right, but not the format.

I just wanted to double check my approach so far, because the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407500/7396516) in the other thread seems to give the reasoning as being ***west*** of or behind UTC, when I'm currently ***east*** or infront, and the two didn't seem compatible as answers

> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", [Date.]parse() assumes a local
> time zone, but given an ISO format such as "2014-03-07" it will assume
> a time zone of UTC.

Comment: What's the "right" format?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `new Date('2022', '09', '24')` will give you the 24th of September 2022 *local time*. If you do `getDate()` you get `24`. Why exactly does it matter what the UTC date is? And if you *do* use the UTC date, chances are that's correct, as it's agnostic to local time.

Comment: `new Date('2022', '09', '24')` gives me `2022-10-23T23:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Hi @caTS, sorry, I should've said, this is what I'm after (don't really care about the time): `2022-10-23T23:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Yes, that's the date in UTC. But when you interrogate the date object itself, you get local date information. Unless you use the `getUTC...` methods.

Comment: When it's midnight on Oct 24 in your time zone, it's 11pm on the 23rd in UTC.  Expected.  Why do you care about UTC time?

Comment: I'm trying desperately not to care about UTC but it won't leave me alone :)

How can I consistently get the date 7 days ago then? This was my previous method `const weekStartDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() -7)`, but that gets the 16th, not the 17th

Comment: That's [a different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) than "off by one (Timezones)". Also, the answer is not really exciting: `date = new Date("2022-03-30"); date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7); console.log(date.getDate())`. The result is `23`, as expected. Even though the clocks moved an hour forward on 27th of March. Similarly `date = new Date("2022-03-23"); date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7); console.log(date.getDate())` results in `30`.

Comment: When I test your above weekStartDate code after changing my timezone I get `Mon Oct 17 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`  check https://jsfiddle.net/923u5bdy/

Comment: @James your console shows it in local format. OP's shows the timestamp in UTC. "Mon Oct 17 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" is "2022-10-16T23:00:00Z" in ISO 8601 format in UTC timezone. Or "2022-10-17T00:00:00+01:00" in ISO 8601 in your local time zone.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ. I'd got the solution to the problem from here (https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-last-week-date#get-last-weeks-date-using-javascript), which apparently was wrong. Anyway, so is there a general rule here? When manipulating dates always use setters/getters? Thanks again, appreciate it

Comment: Yeah. Manipulate the date object and use the date object. That's the general rule. It does not work 100% of the time but it's definitely a start. Re-creating dates is not great. Unless you want to just do a clone with `new Date(oldDateObject)`. Using a date library is also a good idea for anything more complex.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely a lesson it's taught me for future projects. Thanks